# sonataadminbundle DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be a String, Object Given

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony-sonata

When I change the datatime with Sonata, it returns the error:

```
DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

This is my entity:

```
public function setExpiry($dateAsString = null) {
   $this->expiry = new \DateTime($dateAsString);         
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

change the setter like this, because sonata calling it with a DateTime object paramter

```
public function setExpiry(\DateTime $datetime){
    $this->expiry = $datetime;
}
```